# Cant install Google API for Android in Eclipse

Tags: android

Hi i was trying to install google api for android in eclipse with this link 
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ but i dont know it is not installing it is hanging on 26% while installing i waited for 3 hours thought it itakes times but actually i realised that is hanging on 26%, any recomandation?? I alredy have installed android sdk i just need to install google API plug in...

Comment: which version your are tying to install. is your eclipse 3.5?

Comment: I have this version of eclipse 

Version: Helios Release
Build id: 20100617-1415

Answer (score 0):

I don't mean to be condescending here, but that happened to me too, so... Please don't think I'm calling you blind or stupid or anything please. ;^)

Sometimes, there's a little message box hiding under your under other windows, asking you for a confirmation (licence, whatever). It has the joyful habit to pop in the middle of the installation (26% would be a good place to pop, I suppose), so you might not notice it. Once you click on 'OK', 'Accept' or whatever it wants to, the installation should continue.

Comment: there is no msg box, i cant see anywhere

Comment: pls specify it , where does that msgbox appear approximatelly, i cant see any msg box confirmation, if it is like this that stupiditily belongs to the developers of Eclipse :P

Comment: I normally just minimize/close all non-Eclipse windows, one by one, making sure it's not that message box. Then, you can see if it was hidden behind a browser window, something like that. Personally, I'm working on a dual monitor setup, and the message box as a nasty habit of popping on the other monitor, so it's hidden almost behind another window almost any time.

Comment: no i cant see any msgbox, and i dont think it has to do with this, there should be some other problem...

Comment: Well, it was worth trying I suppose. I don't have any idea right now (except to tell you to cancel the operation, close then restart Eclipse, then retry)... Anyway, good luck.